# Scale layout limits on pinch zoom Android?

Tags: android, zooming, pinchzoom

I used a custom layout with a `ScaleGestureDectector` class to zoom in, zoom out my custom view. My problem is when I zoom in at 3.0x and above, my custom layout cannot be zoomed out, and difficult to zoom in (too lag)

Here is my code :

```
private class ScaleGestureListener
        extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

@Override
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    float scaleFactor = mScaleFactor * detector.getScaleFactor();

    mScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
    setScaleX(getScaleX() * mScaleFactor);
    setScaleY(getScaleY() * mScaleFactor);

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I made one example few years back and it was working fine on most of the devices. Not really sure if this helps you but take a look at the answer in the link below,

[How does pinch zoom work with panning for image in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264660/how-does-pinch-zoom-work-with-panning-for-image-in-android/18265133#18265133)